# ¿Como abrir archivo de una extensión con mi programa?

Tags: java, c#, windows-forms, archivo

*Reabro esta pregunta porque pude notar que la anterior vez me expliqué terriblemente mal...
 Además que agregué mucha información innecesaria que causaba confusión.*
La cosa es que tengo un programa Java que genera archivos con una extensión que me inventé (.lvb) para cargarlos en un juego que quiero crear en mi proyecto final.
Pero antes de importarlos a mi juego, me gustaría poder abrirlos de una forma que se me haga comprensible, así que quería crear un segundo programa para visualizar esos archivos.
Entoces tengo un dilema y es que al decirle a Windows que esta extensión se abre con este otro programa.
[image: Ayuda gráfica de a lo que me refiero]
No se a nivel de código como obtener los datos de ese archivo que está abriendo mediante doble clic.
Domino los entornos de Java y Windows Forms en C#, por lo que en cualquiera de los dos lenguajes me sirve.

Comment: No entiendo si tu pregunta es cómo indicarle a windows que cuando un usuario haga doble clic en el archivo invoque tu programa, si es cómo determinar que el programa ha sido invocado desde el shell de Windows para abrir X archivo concreto?

Comment: Casi, para asignarlo lo puedo hacer manualmente. Lo que quiero saber es que una vez asignado, cuando le hago doble clic al archivo y se me abre el programa, que tengo que hacer para que el programa sepa que le estoy pidiendo abrir ese archivo.

Comment: Sugiero entonces que edites tu pregunta para que la redacción quede clara sobre cual es tu duda. Esto aumentará tus probabilidades de obtener la ayuda que esperas. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La *costumbre* en el *shell* de Windows, es pasar el nombre del o de los archivos a abrir  como argumentos de la *línea de comandos* al programa registrado para hacer el caso.

Si haces el registro de manera programática, puedes controlar por ejemplo qué otros argumentos o parámetros se le pasen a tu programa.

En la programación, entonces, se reduce a determinar si tu programa fue invocado con algún argumento y actuar en consecuencia, por ejemplo, suponiendo que:

- puede venir solamente un archivo a abrir
- si viene, siempre será el primer argumento (es lo que el Shell hace normalmente)
- c# como lenguaje de programación
- que ya tienes un método llamado `abrirArchivo` que recibe un string con el nombre del archivo a abrir

La solución podría ser algo como:

```
class MainClass
{
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Si el programa fue invocado con parámetros, llamamos al método
        // correspondiente para abrir el archivo
        if (args.Length > 0) {
            abrirArchivo(args[0]);
        }
        //lo que corresponda...    
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Siempre me pregunté para que era esa String args, ahora tiene bastante sentido. Muchísimas gracias por la ayuda ^-^